# Event Horizon Entanglement Movemen Theory

Tags: event-horizon

Can mathematically/artificially an event horizon be created without the need for the mass of a black hole. i.e. Is there a equivalent mathematical equation/system that has the same characteristics of an event horizon without the identical consequences of the physical event? Time is the key.

Comment: I suggest changing the title of this question to something actually reflective of its content, since I currently can't tell what the title is supposed to have to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rindler coordinates have the [Rindler horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates#The_Rindler_horizon) without any need for a black hole or any mass at all.

Comment: You create a rindler horizon by uniformly accellerating; the horizon is then behind you. Details are on Greg Egan's webpage.